# Deprecation warning createNodeArray since v4.0.0

Tags: npm, migration, angular10, angular11, npm-start

> Deprecation array warning: 'createNodeArray" has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use the appropriate method on 'ts.factory’ or the 'factory’ supplied by your transformation context instead.

Getting this error on nom start after migrating existing angular 10 application into angular 11.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.